# SVN checkout Mac terminal/Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, svn

I need to checkout the SVN code but I am trying from the Xcode and terminal but unable to do that.
My SVN format url starts from url below

`svn://google.com/ad`

I have valid username and password.

Do I need to make SVN to http/https before using it.

Comment: How you are using from terminal ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

what you need to do is this:

```
svn --username user --password password co svn://google.com/ad
```

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode client is little buggy: when you add new repo that require auth,before, you must do at least one operation, such as svn list, via shell.
After this operation, you can add easily repo to your Xcode panel and all works fine.

I hope this may help.

If you have errors, show us.